# Trying to read a two numbers from a text file

Tags: c, file-io, io, string.h

I am trying to read two numbers from a text file. I used `strtok`, and the delimiter is `" "`. The text file (named data.txt) file has only two numbers, the line is `"3 5"`. But the program crashes... any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main(){
    
    FILE *data;
    data = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    
    int m, n;
    char *line, *number;
    while(!feof(data))
    {
        fscanf(data, "%s", line);
        number = strtok(line, " ");     
        m = atoi(number);       
        number = strtok(NULL, " ");     
        n = atoi(number);
    }       
}
```

Comment: `line` is a pointer. What variable or memory space does it point to?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/10622916. In general you should check all return values to be sure that no error occurred.

Comment: `while(!feof(data))` before any read has an undefined behavior, check the value returned by *fscanf*.

Comment: If you're just going to `strtok`, you might as well use `"%d%d"` in the scanf.  But if you are going to use `%s`, you must add a maximum field width which is one less than the size of the buffer.  eg `char line[32]; ... scanf("%31s", line);`.  Since you have allocated zero for the buffer, there's clearly an issue.

Comment: @bruno [while(!feof(data)) before any read has an undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200294/trying-to-read-a-two-numbers-from-a-text-file#comment118782200_67200294) is not supported by the C spec.  `fopen()` --> "The error and end-of-file indicators for the stream are cleared." and `feof()` "function tests the end-of-file indicator for the stream pointed to by stream."  It is well defined, even if it is not what OP should be doing.

Comment: smiili, For robust code, consider other issues: 1) What should happen if the line has 3 numbers? 2) What should happen if the value is outside the `int` range?

Comment: @bruno Nope, it's not UB. It's just bad.

Answer (score 2):

`line` is a uninitialized pointer, it doesn't point to any valid memory location so you can't use it to store data, use an array instead.

`while(!feof(data))` [is not what you'd want to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/6865932) to control your read cycle.

Use `fgets`/`sscanf` to parse the values, simple and easy way to do it:

```
FILE *data;
data = fopen("data.txt", "r");
int m, n;
char line[32];

if (data != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, data)) // assuming that you want to have more lines
    {
        if(sscanf(line, "%d%d", &m, &n) != 2){
            // values not parsed correctly
            //handle parsing error
        }
    }
}
```

Or as [@chux pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200294/trying-to-read-a-two-numbers-from-a-text-file/67200487#comment118783074_67200487), to detect extra junk on the line:

```
 char end;  
 if(sscanf(line, "%d%d %c", &m, &n, &end) != 2) {
     // if more characters exist on the line
     // the return value of sscanf will be 3
 }
```

If the values in the file can be outside the range of an `int` consider using [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead of `sscanf`.

Comment: When the first few characters are not integers, the values of m and n are zero. May I ask how to skip invalid characters?

Comment: @smiili, there is, it helps if you know what those characters are, or at least how many, if not it gets slightly more complicated, maybe a matter for a new question.

Comment: MInor: To detect  extra junk on the line: `char end;  if(sscanf(line, "%d%d %c", &m, &n, &end) != 2){`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's a good adition